# how to add timestamp without Digital Signature

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle, pdfbox

I want to add Time Stamp to my PDF document (without Digital Signature). How can I do this?

I can do it with Digital signature  using Itext ( I have here TSAClient):

```
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, tsa, 0, subfilter);
```

but how to do similar thing without digital signature? using Bouncy Castle or Itext or Pdfbox... or with another library..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iText you are looking for

```
LtvTimestamp.timestamp(appearance, tsa, signatureName);
```

Also cf. the JavaDoc documentation:

```
/**
 * Signs a document with a PAdES-LTV Timestamp. The document is closed at the end.
 * @param sap the signature appearance
 * @param tsa the timestamp generator
 * @param signatureName the signature name or null to have a name generated
 * automatically
 * @throws DocumentException 
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 */
```

You might want to read section 5.4.1 *Adding a Document Security Store (DSS) and a Document-Level Timestamp* in [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures) for the use in context.

Be aware, document level time stamps are not properly recognized by old PDF viewers as they entered the PDF world only fairly recently, i.e. with [PAdES-4](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277804/01.01.02_60/ts_10277804v010102p.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

To do that with PDFBox, you need some simple SignatureInterface implementation like this:

```
public class TimestampSignatureImpl implements SignatureInterface {
    private TSAClient tsaClient;
    public TimestampSignatureImpl(TSAClient tsaClient) {
        super();
        this.tsaClient = tsaClient;
    }
    @Override
    public byte[] sign(InputStream paramInputStream) throws IOException {
        return tsaClient.getTimeStampToken(IOUtils.toByteArray(paramInputStream));
    }
}
```

and some PDSignature like this:

```
PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE); 
signature.setSubFilter(COSName.getPDFName("ETSI.RFC3161"));
signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());
```

Then sign your pdf like this:

```
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
TSAClient tsaClient = new TSAClient(new URL("your time stamp authority"), null, null, digest);
pdf.addSignature(signature, new TimestampSignatureImpl(tsaClient));
pdf.saveIncremental(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
pdf.close();
```

P.S: TSAClient is taken from PDFBox examples.

Answer (score 0):

Using `iText7` you can add `DTS` ***(Document Timestamping)*** by invoking the following method of `PdfSigner` class.

```
ITSAClient tsa = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl, tsaUser, tsaPass);
pdfSigner.timestamp(tsa, "SignatureTimeStamp");
```

***or***

```
ITSAClient tsa = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl, tsaUser, tsaPass, 8192, "SHA-256"); 
pdfSigner.timestamp(tsa, "SignatureTimeStamp");
```

Also, java documentation

```
/**
 * Signs a document with a PAdES-LTV Timestamp. The document is closed at the end.
 * NOTE: This method closes the underlying pdf document. This means, that current instance
 * of PdfSigner cannot be used after this method call.
 *
 * @param tsa           the timestamp generator
 * @param signatureName the signature name or null to have a name generated
 *                      automatically
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 */
```